# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'. StandardWrapper.Throwable

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

All 
I am developing a simple login project, and trying to get the app running in the tomcat server, I've had several issues with the "cannot change project facet dynamic web module version errors" as well." tried to solve it by changing the versions of the module and making sure appropriate java jee is also present. but failed. Now having this server context initialization failed error. as well. can someone help me out.
Thanks in advance

SampleLoginApp-servlet.xml:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.Controller"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>


    <bean id="jspviewresolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SampleLoginApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>SampleLoginApp</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SampleLoginApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SampleLoginApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SampleLoginApp-servlet.xml`, you have declared  `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`

I don't see that the `xsi:schemaLocation` is defined for it. Can you try by adding the following line

```
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now the console shows, no errors, but the tomcat will not display any thing on the local host except showing error.

Comment: Now, the problem lies somewhere else. Can you post the controller class and the error that you are getting?